# Why does this for loop multiplies everything?

Tags: python

This is the stripped down code:

```
import itertools

def Compare(file1, file2):

    with open(file1+'.txt', 'r') as f1, open(file2+'.txt', 'r') as f2:
        for line in itertools.product(f1, f2):
            print (line),
```

It will always print out every line in the number of the total lines that are present.
So if there are 4 lines in total in the specific txt file, it will print each line 4 times so the result would be 16 lines that 12 of them are repeats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what `itertools.product` does - takes each element in `a` and pairs it with all elements in `b`.If you want each line from each file paired, then you want to look at `itertools.izip`, eg:

```
from itertools import product, izip
from pprint import pprint

a = ['a_one', 'a_two', 'a_three']
b = ['b_one', 'b_two', 'b_three']

pprint(list(product(a, b)))
[('a_one', 'b_one'),
 ('a_one', 'b_two'),
 ('a_one', 'b_three'),
 ('a_two', 'b_one'),
 ('a_two', 'b_two'),
 ('a_two', 'b_three'),
 ('a_three', 'b_one'),
 ('a_three', 'b_two'),
 ('a_three', 'b_three')]

pprint(list(izip(a, b)))
[('a_one', 'b_one'), ('a_two', 'b_two'), ('a_three', 'b_three')]
```

If you're aiming to compare files, then it'll be worth looking at the [filecmp](http://docs.python.org/2/library/filecmp.html) and [difflib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html) modules.

Comment: could you possibly provide a brief example of filecmp in this context?

Comment: @MaxPower there's plenty of examples in the Python docs and code samples elsewhere... I'm sure you'll be able to find one that meets your needs or provides a suitable template to work with

Answer (score 2):

Because `itertools.product` is essentially multiplying the two lists together.

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html):

> cartesian product, equivalent to a nested for-loop

4 lines multiplied by 4 lines is going to be 16 lines.